# Core Graphics & Gradients

Tags: ios, swift

could some one tell me why i have error when declaring let = Gradient

```
contectual type CFArray can not be used with array literal
```

with this code - which is just a background gradient, which i thought would be better than using a vector..

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    //// General Declarations
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    //// Color Declarations
    let gradientColor = UIColor(red: 0.180, green: 0.808, blue: 0.831, alpha: 0.196)
    let gradientColor2 = UIColor(red: 0.200, green: 0.282, blue: 0.392, alpha: 1.000)

    //// Gradient Declarations
    let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [gradientColor2.CGColor, gradientColor2.blendedColorWithFraction(0.5, ofColor: gradientColor).CGColor, gradientColor.CGColor], [0, 1, 1])!

    //// Rectangle Drawing
    let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 667))
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    rectanglePath.addClip()
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPoint(x: 187.5, y: -0), CGPoint(x: 187.5, y: 667), CGGradientDrawingOptions())
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)



}
```

}

Comment: Might be something going on with blendedColorWithFraction? If I use an array of [UIColor.redColor().CGColor, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor] it compiles without complaint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all that means is that you can't pass a swift array to the CGGradientCreateWithColors function. You need to turn that array in a CFArray like so:

```
let gradientArray = [gradientColor2.CGColor, gradientColor.CGColor]
let arrayPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Void>>(gradientArray)
let cfArray = CFArrayCreate(nil, arrayPointer, gradientArray.count, nil)
```

Then pass that CFArray reference to the function:

```
let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), cfArray, [0, 1, 1])!
```

Comment: well that worked! i need to try and work out what you mean...i think it might be above me for now... :( but thank you, i will read up on this

Comment: No worries! The issue comes because that API expects a pointer to C array, whereas swift creates value types for arrays. If you want to learn a bit more, try having a look at learning some C, specifically the difference between a pointer and a value. It can be quite intense if you're used to programming in higher level languages, but it's really informative to have an idea of whats going on under the hood. This online course is a great place to start http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/